# Can I Remove Push.SetSenderID(string) Now That It's Obsolete?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-push

Is it safe to remove the line of code that calls `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.SetSenderId`, which has been marked `obsolete`?

I updated [Microsoft.AppCenter.Push](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AppCenter.Push/), increased the Xamarin.Android target framework to 8.1, updated `AndroidManifest.xml`, added `google-services.json` and updated the proguard config following these steps:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android/?WT.mc_id=none-github-bramin)

However, the following warning is unclear as to whether I can safely delete `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.SetSenderId`:

> 'Push.SetSenderId(string)' is obsolete: 'For all the Android developers using App Center, there is a change coming where Firebase SDK is required to use Push Notifications. For Android P, its scheduled at the release date for the latest OS version. For all other versions of Android, it will be required after April 2019. Please follow the migration guide at [https://aka.ms/acfbxa](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android/?WT.mc_id=none-github-bramin).' (CS0618)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely delete `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.SetSenderId` once you have completed the [recommended steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android/?WT.mc_id=none-github-bramin):

- Increase the Xamarin.Android target framework to 8.1
- Update `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Add `google-services.json` from Firebase

After completing the recommended steps, `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.SetSenderId` will no longer execute any code in the SDK (it is essentially a no-op).